# Martingale representation theorem and Itô's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $W_t=\int_0^t dW_s$ be a wiener process and let $Y_t = Y_t(W_t)$ be a martingale. By the martingale representation theorem $dY_t = h_t dW_t$ for some unique, predictable process $h_t$. Given that we know that $Y_T = g(W_T)$ for some function $g(x)$ and at some time point $T$, is it possible to find $h_t$ for $t<T$?

Intuitively I had the idea to apply Itô's lemma at the time $T$ to get 
\begin{equation}
dY_T = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(W_T) dW_T
\end{equation}
and identify $h_T = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(W_T)$ and then simply let $h_t = E[h_T | \mathcal{F}_t]$. This actually seems to work for the specific problem I'm looking at, but it's not exactly formal and I don't think it would hold as a proof. Is there any validity to this idea? What other methods could be used to find $h_t$?

Comment: How do you get this expression for $dY_T$? Applying Itô's formula gives another term of the form $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} g(W_T) \, dT$. If you are looking for some more examples how to calculate $g$, just search for "martingale representation theorem".

Comment: Since it's a martingale I don't expect there to be any drift terms.

Comment: Well, even if you don't expect that there is a drift term, Itô's formula is telling you that there **is** a drift term if you apply it to $g(W_T)$.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1748107/36150) and [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1275966/36150).