# Using Ito Calculus to find $\mathbb{E}[U_t]$ if $U_t= \cos(\sigma W_t)$ where $W_t$ is Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Related: [Ito integral representation of cosine of Brownian motion and expected value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222976/ito-integral-representation-of-cosine-of-brownian-motion-and-expected-value)

**Question**:

> *Let, $U_t = \cos(\sigma W_t)$, $W_t$ is Brownian Motion. Find $dU_t$ and hence find $\mathbb{E}[U_t]$.*

I've found $dU_t$ to be:

$$
dU_t = - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_t) dW_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \cos(\sigma W_t) dt
$$

I'm not sure how to find the expected value of $U_t$ using Ito Calculus.

In the linked question, the author makes a change of variable like so:
$X_T = e^{\frac{1}{2}t} \cos B_t$

I'm not sure where the $e^{\frac{1}{2}t}$ comes from when the original question says: $X_T = \cos(B_T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, make the variable change $X_t=e^{\frac12\sigma^2t}U_t$. Then, with Ito's rule,

$$dX_t = -e^{\frac12\sigma^2t}\sigma \sin(\sigma W_t) dW_t $$

which is drift-less (or a martingale). Therefore,

$$E[e^{\frac12\sigma^2t}U_t] = E[X_t] = X_0=1$$

or

$$E[U_t] = e^{-\frac12\sigma^2t}$$

Comment: how do you prove that $dX_t$ is a martingale? Is it obvious and can be stated without proof?

Comment: @s5s - It may not be rigorous; a drift-less process is nominally a margingale. For this problem, you do not really need it; it is enough to have $E[\int_0^t \sin(\sigma W_t)dW_t]=0$ to establish $E[X_t]=X_0$.

Comment: @Quanto The usual way of proving that is to prove that the Ito integral is a martingale though. Do you have another method in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_t = \mathbb{E}[U_t]$. Writing your results from Ito's formula in integral form and taking expectations we find that
$$u_t = \mathbb{E}[U_t] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^t - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s)dW_s \bigg] - \mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac12 \int_0^t \sigma^2 U_s ds \bigg]$$

Now the first term on the right hand side is the expectation of a martingale started from $0$ and hence is $0$. By Fubini's theorem the second term is $-\frac12 \int_0^t \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[U_s] ds$. Hence we find that $u_t$ satisfies the ODE
$$\frac{du_t}{dt} = - \frac12 \sigma^2 u_t$$

Hence $u_t = \exp(-\frac12 \sigma^2 t)$.

Comment: it's not obvious to me that $\int_0^t - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s)dW_s$ is a martingale. Is it obvious? If not, how do you prove this?

Comment: (1/2) You can think of this as being part of the construction of the stochastic integral. For example, fix $T \in (0,\infty]$. Then for $t \in [0,T]$ you have $\int_0^t - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s) dW_s = \int_0^t- \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s) dW_s^T$ where $W_s^T$ is the Brownian motion stopped at time $T$. Since $W_s^T$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale, the construction of the Ito integral tells us that the stochastic integral $ \int_0^t - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s) dW_s^T$ is also an $L^2$-bounded martingale as long as $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^T \sigma^2 \sin(\sigma W_s)^2] < \infty$ which is easily verified.

Comment: (2/2) From the above you then conclude that martingale property holds on the interval $[0,T]$. Since $T$ is arbitrary, this tells you that martingale property holds at all times so that the integral is itself a martingale. Notice however that this argument does not tell you that the integral is $L^2$-bounded since we are only able to conclude that $\{\int_0^t - \sigma \sin(\sigma W_s) dW_s: t \in [0,T]\}$ is $L^2$-bounded for each $T$. The bounds you get could blow-up as you send $T \to \infty$.